# Django custom ManyToMany relation name

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

Consider the following 2 models:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Tag({self.name})"

class Exercise(models.Model):
    name = name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='exercises')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Exercise({self.name})"
```

In `admin.py`:

```
admin.site.register(Tag)
```

When deleting a tag from the admin panel, a warning with relation object names are displayed which is not really informative.

```
# Are you sure you want to delete tag3 ? The following elements will be deleted too.
Tag: tag3

    Relation exercise-tag: Exercise_tags object (3)
    Relation exercise-tag: Exercise_tags object (6)
    Relation exercise-tag: Exercise_tags object (9)
```

How can one make a more informative message by displaying the actual exercise name instead of the relation name e.g `Exercise_tags object (3)` ?

For instance:

```
# Are you sure you want to delete tag3 ? The following elements will be deleted too.
Tag: tag3

    Relation exercise-tag: Advanced exercise 5
    Relation exercise-tag: Introductory exercise on programming
    Relation exercise-tag: My exercise 2
```

Comment: Defining a `through` model and overriding its `__str__` method should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add `__str__` method to your models. Not 100% sure, but it should solve this issue.

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

The `__str__` method is used in many of places by Django.
"Most notably, to display an object in the Django admin site and as the value inserted into a template when it displays an object. Thus, you should always return a nice, human-readable representation of the model"

---

Ok, so it turned out that the upper solution did not work.
Maybe you should consider redesigning your model from ManyToMany relation to a Foreign key relation, as follows:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Tag({self.name})"

class Exercise(models.Model):
    name = name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Exercise({self.name})"

class TagExercise(models.Model):
    exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Exercise({self.exercise}/{self.tag})"
```

In this way when deleting a specific tag from admin will display informative name.

Comment: This does not resolve the issue. I could add a `__str__` to Tag or Exercise but it won't be for the Exercise_tags relation.